# LookupError: unknown encoding: -

Tags: python

I've been getting this error and have no idea how to fix it. Any ideas?

filler because i have to add some more details and have no idea what to write more so ignore this

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage
import mysql.connector


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host='localhost',
  database='notgettingthis',
  user='neitherthis',
  password='verynicepass'
)

cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

food1m = "SELECT * FROM thing WHERE fhfhfhf='e' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;"
cursor.execute(thing)
thing1 = cursor.fetchone()[1]
thing2 = cursor.fetchone()[1]
thing3 = cursor.fetchone()[1]
thing4 = cursor.fetchone()[1]


msg1 = EmailMessage()
msg1.set_content("""blablablablablablablabla:

-""", str(thing1), """
-""", str(thing2), """
-""", str(thing3), """
-""", str(thing4)
)
msg1["Subject"] = "subject"
msg1["From"] = "example@gmail.com"
msg1["To"] = "exampple@gmail.com"

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.example.com", port=587) as smtp:
    smtp.starttls(context=context)
    smtp.login(msg1["From"], "pass")
    smtp.send_message(msg1)
```

Full error and traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Lundqvist\Desktop\food\weekstuff.py", line 24, in <module>
    msg1.set_content("""Las comidas que tu vas a preparar esta semana son las siguientes:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\email\message.py", line 1171, in set_content
    super().set_content(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\email\message.py", line 1101, in set_content
    content_manager.set_content(self, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\email\contentmanager.py", line 37, in set_content
    handler(msg, obj, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\email\contentmanager.py", line 185, in set_text_content
    cte, payload = _encode_text(string, charset, cte, msg.policy)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\email\contentmanager.py", line 143, in _encode_text
    lines = string.encode(charset).splitlines()
LookupError: unknown encoding:
-
```

Comment: Can you include the full error and traceback?

Comment: @jordanm now did

Answer (score 0):

The `set_content` method perceives all of these:

```py
"""blablablablablablablabla:

-""", str(thing1), """
-""", str(thing2), """
-""", str(thing3), """
-""", str(thing4)
```

as separate parameters since they're separated by commas. I'm assuming you want to send all of these concatenated together to the `msg` parameter  (see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.contentmanager.html#email.contentmanager.ContentManager.set_content)).

Change

```py
msg1.set_content("""blablablablablablablabla:

-""", str(thing1), """
-""", str(thing2), """
-""", str(thing3), """
-""", str(thing4)
)
```

to

```py
msg1.set_content("""blablablablablablablabla:

-""" + str(thing1) + """
-""" + str(thing2) + """
-""" + str(thing3) + """
-""" + str(thing4)
)
```

Comment: tried that and got this error: socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: That's not an error related to this question! You should be able to fix this yourself but if you can't, post a different question about it since it's a different issue.